# Transceiver IC for radar

Tags: rf, modulation, transceiver

I'm trying to build a radar that functions in the ISM bands (433 MHz, 915 MHz, 2.4 GHz and 5.8 GHz). I'm trying to look for RF transceiver ICs that operate in these bands.

Most of the ICs I'm finding tend to be for digital communication (ASK, FSK modulation types). I would ideally like a transceiver IC that operates based on IQ baseband signal modulation.

I've found some chips from analog devices (LTC5586, ADL5380 etc) which take IQ signals and and produce the RF output as I want, but they are just modulator ICs (not a full transceiver with the input filters etc). Ideally, I would like a fully integrated transceiver.

Is there a workaround way to use the digital communication transceiver ICs that I am finding for my purpose? Why are the analog modulation chips so difficult to find? Am I looking in the wrong place possibly?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE Shopping questions (which this appears to be) are off topic here.  If you reword the question (perhaps to ask why fully integrated transceivers are not apparently easily available) it would fit within the scope of the site.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've edited it. Hopefully I can get some answers now...

Answer (score 0):

Analog devices makes a number of IQ transceiver ICs.  The AD9361 (similar to the chip used in the inexpensive ADALM Pluto) operates in all of the bands mentioned.  The ADRV9008 is a newer chip with similar capabilities.

The chips used for SDR transceivers are all IQ-based.  Lime makes a single-chip solution.  Or you can look at how it is done in the HackRF, using a baseband IQ transciever paired with an RF synthesizer.  If you go with a multi-chip solution, your options explode.

These devices are high-bandwidth devices that are frequently paired with an FPGA.

If you are on a budget and can restrict yourself to ISM frequencies below 1GHz, the CMX991 should work.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for your reply. I went with an LTC5586 IQ demodulator + ADL5375 IQ modulator + ADF4351 frequency synthesizer in the end. I won't be able to work with the 5.8 GHz band, but should be able to do everything else if all goes well. The chip you suggest (CMX991) would have been brilliant if I'd seen your message earlier :). But I think they are difficult to get your hands (digikey is out of stock). Thanks anyway!